# php image download and date correction

Tags: php

i have made a simple image downloader for my image hosting site. I am facing one problem though. When i download the image its broken and i cant get a piece of code right. Someone please take a look.

So my images are store in my image.uploads folder by date. So i need to get the image date before downloading it. heres what i got so far.

```
<?php   

if(isset($_POST['file_name'])){
$file = $_POST['file_name'];
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
header('Content-type: image/png');
header('Content-type: image/gif');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
    readfile('image.uploads/' . date("jS F Y", $image_details->image_date) . '/'.$file);
exit();
}

?>
```

idk if i got the image date part right and how owould i make it show like this: "25-07-13" :/
The html part: $image_main is the images name.

```
<form action="view-image.php" method="post" name="downloadform">
  <input name="file_name" value="<?=$image_main?>" type="hidden">
  <input type="submit" value="Download the image">
</form>
```

Thanks alot for anyone who is willing to help!

Comment: Remember to add some security! What happens if I post `file_name=../../../etc/someSecretConfigFile` to your script?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're setting the wrong Content-type, I set these header when I download a file:

```
header("Content-Type: ".$mime);
header("Cache-   Control: no-store, no-cache");
header("Content-Description: ".$mustang);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=".$mustang);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

Where `$mime` is the mime-type and `$mustang` is the file name, basically what you are trying to do is not correct, because the setted contet-type is always image/gif
To find out the mime-type of a file use the php function `finfo_open`